# What is an English word which means 'bêtement'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation, idioms

*Bêtement* is a French word whose literal meaning is 'in the manner of an animal'. It is often used metaphorically, to describe an action carried out in a robotic fashion – without thinking. How would you translate this sense into English? Perhaps *robotically* is the answer, but can anyone think of anything better?

Comment: What did your French-English ditionary already say?

Comment: It said 'stupidly'. Hachette is a good dictionary, recommended by professionals, but on this occasion I do not believe it has got it right.

Comment: In my experience, the French will use _bêtement_ in exactly the same way as I use _stupidly_. While true that the origin of the word is _bête_ as in _beast_, in everyday speech, it is used to mean _fool_ or _idiot_. _Il est bête_ does not translate into _he's a beast_ but into _he's an idiot_. I think your dictionary is quite right.

Comment: @terdon. Sounds as if you live in France, in which case 'who am I to argue?'. But from when I lived in France I could remember people in my company using it to describe the actions of a clerk who had simply transcribed something out of habit, mechanically, without even noticing that what they had written had been ridiculous. 'Stupidly' does not seem to me, precisely, to cover that.

Comment: First of all, yes I live in France but I am not a native speaker of French (or even close), so don't take my word as gospel. That said, _bêtement_ in that context means _automatically_, i.e. without thinking, not _like an animal_ so again, it is close to _foolish_. Also see Mark Thorin's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bêtement has other meanings than the one you are referring to, but in this case, when you do something without thinking, you do it **mindlessly**.

"She *mindlessly* passed me on the street without even giving a hint of recognition."

"I have been *mindlessly* driving to work everyday, and never noticed that our beloved oak tree was gone."

[mindlessly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mindlessly): Giving or showing little attention or care; heedless.

You might consider the French phrase *Que je suis bête !* to mean "I am stupid!" (Am I stupid!), but a more subtle meaning might be "What was I thinking!" which is a short distance from "I wasn't thinking". In other words, "I was acting mindlessly" ( Je me comportais bêtement ) .

Comment: Excellent. precisely the word I was searching for! I consider you to have answered my question exactly.

Comment: @WS2 if this is the case, you should mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Lumberjack. Thanks. I've discovered how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

**"Bêtement" is by no means associated with ideas of insanity, and even less of bestiality.**

It is a *very mild word* to say "foolishly".

"Zut, j'ai bêtement oublié mes clefs !" = "Oops, I have foolishly forgotten my keys !"

and "tout bêtement" means "quite simply"

"Alors, je suis rentré tout bêtement par la fenêtre". = "Then, I quite simply went in through the window".

and "une bêtise" = a not really important blunder.

*A Franco-British*

Answer (score 1):

The most common animal metaphor relevant here is that of cattle - so you can say *in a [**bovine**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bovine) manner* thus denoting their dull and stolid mechanical nature.

Bovine is apt in this figurative sense. Continuing the animal metaphors you may prefer ***mutton-headed***, which basically carries the same meaning of being dull and slow-witted.

A good non-animal robotic metaphor is ***automaton-like***.

Comment: Why did this answer get voted down? as the person who asked the question I thought it was quite good, not as good as 'mechanical', but not too far adrift. I'm new to all this, but what is the meaning of all these negative votes?

Comment: I wouldn't consider this answer to require a downvote. The word 'bovine' _does have_ a spread of secondary senses of 'stolid / plodding / sluggish' in most dictionaries. But if you search for _bovine_ on the web, you'll find yourself starting with dictionary references, then the principal sense and a few quirky usages, with hardly an example of the 'sluggish' usage for ages.

Answer (score 0):

The standard translations of *bêtement* are words like *stupidly*, *idiotically*, *insanely* or *thoughtlessly*, carrying the metaphorical meaning of "like a beast".

Answer (score 0):

'Mechanically' comes up as the best fit. It is unusual to find a French word for which there is no exact equivalent in English, since English has a larger vocabulary than French. I can think of dozens of English words for which it is difficult to find a French equivalent, the most obvious ones being 'home', 'fair', 'cosy' etc. I'm not an expert, but it is sometimes said that whilst the English rely on vocabulary to shade their meanings and alter the nuance, the French achieve a similar effect through inflections of grammar, in particular through the use of the subjunctive.

Since writing this @ Jim has suggested the word 'mindlessly' for this particular meaning of the word betement. This would seem to me to fit precisely, though I do of course recognise that betement has other meanings.

Comment: 'Metronomically' is in the same ballpark. Corral.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Sounds good but the problem is I've never heard anyone speak of someone having done something 'metronomically'.

Comment: [Yes, you have a problem.](http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/mess-micr/metronomically/) I don't: 'But when Bloomberg is gone, New Yorkers will have the chance to elect someone who is not incessantly and metronomically invoking the business model of governance.' Also, 'Everything on the British end of things is working metronomically.' / '...she broke Cibulkova to love, her forehand working metronomically...' / 'Al Di Meola is a master of the guitar, and it may seem like his timing is off, but his mind is working metronomically ...' (internet). Do check your facts.

Comment: If you prefer a sentient agent: 'where you walk calmly and metronomically, no jerky movements' //

' ...on his round throne, surrounded by metronomically nodding courtiers' //


'Mindlessly, metronomically blipping through channel after channel' //

'Carrick keeps things going metronomically, down the left and then down the right.'  //

'A cow was shambling down the center of Main Bazaar Road, metronomically [swishing] her tail at the flies' (all internet)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ***mechanically,*** although if you'd like to allude to the French word's “beast” etymology, you can also use ***instinctively.*** Both mean “unthinking”; *instinctive* is somewhat more positive, while *mechanical* is somewhat negative.

Comment: Note that this is only for the stated context. In other contexts, Mark Thorin's _foolishly_ would be better.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps *[bestial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bestial)*?

> 1. brutal or savage
> 2. sexually depraved; carna
> 3. lacking in refinement; brutish
> 4. of or relating to a beast

Also consider *[beastly](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/beastly)*

> Of or resembling a beast; bestial.

If you are just asking about an unthinking manner, your term *robotically* may be appropriate. You also could consider *[mechanically](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mechanical?view=uk)*

> (of an action) done without thought or spontaneity; automatic

The terms *drone-like* and *sheep-like* are also used to suggest automaton like behavior.

Comment: I think 'mechanically' is perhaps the best fit. Oddly the dictionaries do not include it. Hachette says 'stupidly', which is well wide. The earlier suggestions you mention are an altogether different use of the word.

Comment: The adverbs are _bestially_ and _beastlily_ (no relation to tiger lily).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth.  But those have a quite different meaning. Indeed the French use the words 'bestial' and 'bestialite' and they mean what they mean in English. 'Betement' is something else.

Comment: Why the downward voting?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. I should have said 'a French word whose LITERAL meaning is "in the manner of an animal"'. Is it not legitimate to search on this site for an English word which means something, and the only way of expressing that 'something' is by using a word in another language which describes it? The Japanese, for example, have a word, spelled in Roman letters,  'kimochi'. I would be delighted if someone could point me to an English equivalent which I could use in Wigan or Wolverhampton.